# Why does this poisson distribution implementation return 0 on msvc

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am curious why the following implementation always return 0 using the visual studio compiler, but it works fine when compiled with gcc and clang

```
int poissrand(double lambda){
  int k=0;
  double L=exp(-lambda), p=1;
  do {
    ++k;
    p *= rand()/(double)INT_MAX;
  } while (p > L);
  return --k;
}
```

Examples [here](http://rextester.com/HLRH41032) (vc) and [here](http://rextester.com/PPMP19805) (gcc)

Comment: Call `srand(time(null))` in main before the loop.

Comment: I forgot to insert srand in the example but it does not make a difference, and  the question is tagged c because I cannot use c++ in this case

Comment: Perhaps because in MSVC the range of `rand()` is different. There is no `RAND_MAX` in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MSVC the range of `rand()` is different. In all versions it is specified by `RAND_MAX` in `stdlib.h`.

If the value you multiply `p` by is supposed to be in the range `0..1` then please try

```
p *= (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
```